# error in updating records using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-query-builder

i'm trying to update my records which are stored in the database, but unfortunately i'm getting  errors like (given below) this please can any one help me in this it would be help full for me

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$id
>
> Filename: views/display_about_us1.php
>
> Line Number: 44
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter_try\application\views\display_about_us1.php
>   Line: 44
>
> Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter_try\application\controllers\Home.php
>   Line: 107
>   Function: view
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter_try\index.php
>   Line: 315
>   Function: require_once

**Controller**

```
public function updatedata()
{
$id=$this->input->get('id');
$result['data']=$this->Contact_model->displayrecordsById($id);
$this->load->view('update_about_us1',$result);  

if($this->input->post('update'))
    {
        // Basic validation
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_content', 'First content', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('second_content', 'Second content', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('third_content', 'Third content', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('fourth_content', 'Fourth content', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('update_about_us1'); 
        }

        else
        {
            $id = $this->input->post('id');
            $data = array();
            $data['first_content']=$this->input->post('first_content');
            $data['second_content']=$this->input->post('second_content');
            $data['third_content']=$this->input->post('third_content');
            $data['fourth_content']=$this->input->post('fourth_content');
            $this->Contact_model->updaterecords($id, $data);
            redirect("Home/About_us_display");
        }
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
function displayrecordsById($id)
{
        $query=$this->db->query("select * from about_us1 where id='".$id."'");
        return $query->result();
}

function updaterecords($id,$data)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('about_us1', $data);
}
```

**View**

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
            <title>About_us1 page</title>
            </head>

            <body>
             <?php
              $i=1;
              foreach($data as $row)
              {
              ?>
                <form action="Home/updatedata" method="get">
                    <table width="600" border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
              <tr>
                <td width="230">First content </td>
                <td width="329"><textarea rows="4" cols="50"  name="first_content" value="<?php echo $row->first_content; ?>"/></textarea></td>
                <span><?php echo form_error("first_content");?></span>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Second content </td>
                <td><textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="second_content" value="<?php echo $row->second_content; ?>"/></textarea></td>
                <span><?php echo form_error("second_content");?></span>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Third content </td>
                <td><textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="third_content" value="<?php echo $row->third_content; ?>"/></textarea></td>
                <span><?php echo form_error("third_content");?></span>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Fourth content </td>
                <td><textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="fourth_content" value="<?php echo $row->fourth_content; ?>"/></textarea></td>
                <span><?php echo form_error("fourth_content");?></span>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update Records"/></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
                </form>
                <?php } ?>
            </body>
            </html>




            // display record view page 



            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
                <head>
                    <title>display</title>
                    <meta charset="utf-8">
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
                    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                </head>

                <body>
                    <br><br>
                    <div class="container">

                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading text-center">Contact Us Details</div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="table-responsive">          
                            <table class="table">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>ID</th>
                                        <th>First Content</th>
                                        <th>Second Content</th>
                                        <th>Third Content</th>
                                        <th>Fourth Content</th>
                                        <th>Update Content</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <?php
                                            $i=1;
                                            foreach($data as $row)
                                            {
                                                echo "<tr>";
                                                echo "<td>".$i."</td>";
                                                echo "<td>".$row->first_content."</td>";
                                                echo "<td>".$row->second_content."</td>";
                                                echo "<td>".$row->third_content."</td>";
                                                echo "<td>".$row->fourth_content."</td>";
                                                echo "<td><a href='updatedata?id=".$row->id."'>Update</a></td>";
                                                echo "</tr>";
                                                $i++;
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>  
                            </table>
                        </div><br><br>

                        <a href="<?php echo site_url("Home/backend"); ?>" style="margin-left: 40%"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Back</button></a>

                    </div>
                </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: updaterecords accepts 5 argument while you providing array.

Comment: From where are you getting the value of id? you are getting the value by get method and you are posting the form by post method.

Comment: sorry sir it did not solved my problem @ri

Comment: please check my update question sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

Arguments mismatch with `updaterecords` method in controller with model

***Should be like this :***

Call `updaterecords` method in your controller like this :

```
$this->Contact_model->updaterecords($id, $data);
```

Your model method should be like this :

```
function updaterecords($id,$data,)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('about_us1', $data);
}
```

UPDATE :

your controller code should be like this :

```
if($this->input->post('update'))
{
    $data = array();
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $data['first_content']=$this->input->post('first_content');
    $data['second_content']=$this->input->post('second_content');
    $data['third_content']=$this->input->post('third_content');
    $data['fourth_content']=$this->input->post('fourth_content');
    $this->Contact_model->updaterecords($id, $data);
    redirect("Home/About_us_display");
}
```

Comment: make sure u have `$id` in your method `updaterecords` by echoing

Comment: make sure what ur form method type is and get `$id` according to form method type

Comment: ur not passing update id with your form u should have a hidden field id which must have id of the record to be updated

Comment: change your form method `post` from `get` should be like this : `<form action="Home/updatedata" method="post">`

Comment: sir its working i edited few things but i need ur help in one more issue  want to use text area instead of input but when im trying to use that na its not working

Comment: <textarea class="form-control" name="first_content" value="<?php echo $row->first_content; ?>"></textarea>

Comment: it should be like this : `<textarea class="form-control" name="first_content" ><?php echo $row->first_content; ?></textarea>`

Comment: just a small help sir, the image which i have uploaded to the folder i want to display it in my table. so i have tried with this code but its not working please can u guide me a bit please`echo "<td>".<img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/'.$row->filename);?>" alt="" width="100%" height="100%">."</td>";`

Comment: Should be like this : `echo '<td><img src="'. base_url('uploads/'.$row->filename).'" alt="" width="100%" height="100%"></td>';`

Comment: does my answer helps you

Comment: so pls don't hesitate to upvote my answer and check it as green

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51279050/unable-to-update-my-data-with-validation

Comment: please can u check this link sir please